# How to install SSL on GCE [Wordpress + Apache]

Tags: wordpress, apache, ssl, google-compute-engine

I created a privatekey file using openssl command:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out private.key 2048
```

Entered my password, and followed by generating CSR:

```
openssl req -new -key privatekey.key -out csrkey.csr
```

I use this CSR key to create my SSL certificate through RapidSSL. They issued me 3 certificate ending in .cer namely:

1. CACertificate-1.cer
2. CACertificate-2.cer
3. ServerCertificate-1.cer

I uploaded all of these certificates to the /etc/apache2/ folder

/etc/apache2/ contains:

- CACertificate-1.cer
- CACertificate-2.cer
- ServerCertificate-1.cer
- Privatekey.key
- Csrkey.csr
- Chain.ctr ([I got this from Rapid SSL as an intermidiate certificate](https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&id=SO6252&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US))

I then had to add the code to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
SSLEngine on
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName example.co.uk
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/CACertificate-1.cer
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/privatekey.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/chain.ctr
</VirtualHost>
```

My `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file didn't have the `<VirtualHost>`, when I tried to restart apache it it said "SSLEngine command not deined in this module". So I have a look around and found `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf` which did contain `<VirtualHost>`

I proceeded by adding the code above, but after restarting apache using

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

> But the https://example.co.uk is giving me a grey screen: SSL connection error
>
> ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR Hide details Unable to make a secure connection
>   to the server. This may be a problem with the server, or it may be
>   requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.

Comment: Slight update for 2018, you can use https://letsencrypt.org/ to automatically handle this process on your Apache server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps to enable HTTPS protocol of your Apache service on Google Compute Engine (You can safely skip those steps that you've already taken) :

1. Create a secure directory to install and protect your keys

`$ sudo mkdir /etc/apache2/ssl.crt` 
`$ cd /etc/apache2/ssl.crt`

2. Generate a private key

`$ sudo openssl genrsa -out example.key 2048`

3. Generate a certificate signing request (CSR)

`$ sudo openssl req -new -key example.key -out example.csr`

4. You can use your new CSR to obtain a valid certificate from a certificate authority (CA). Alternatively, you can generate a self-signed certificate by running the following command

`$ sudo openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in example.csr -signkey example.key -out example.crt`

> Caution: Self-signed certificates are not suitable for public sites.
>   While a self-signed certificate implements full encryption, it will
>   cause most browsers to present a warning or error when visitors try to
>   access your site. The above command is provided for testing purposes
>   only.

5. Open Apache’s SSL site configuration file for editing

`$ sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf`

6. Edit the following directives’ values

`SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/example.crt`

`SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/example.key`

7. Uncomment and edit SSLCertificateChainFile value, if you got a certificate chain file from your CA

`SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/server-ca.crt`

8. Save the configuration file and close it.
9. Now enable this site configuration file

`$ sudo a2ensite default-ssl.conf`

10. You can use the command below to verify and see configuration errors

`$ sudo apachectl configtest`

11. Restart the Apache service

`$ sudo service apache2 restart`

12. Add/Enable GCE firewall rules for the following protocol:ports pairs for your VM instance

`tcp:80 and tcp:443`