# Enable SSL on Tomcat on Google Compute Engine

Tags: tomcat, ssl, https

I'm trying to enable SSL on Tomcat on GCE.

1. I installed Let's Encrypt certificate by following this:

https://certbot.eff.org/#ubuntutyakkety-apache

2. Scanned the certificate here:

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=mydomain.com

it checks out.

3. Configured tomcat by following this:

https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/how-to-use-the-certificate-for-tomcat/3677

Connector in my server.xml looks like this:

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" 
           URIEncoding="UTF-8" maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https"
           secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreFile="/home/me/certs/MyKeystore.jks" 
           keystorePass="password" keyAlias="tomcat" keyPass="password"/>
```

After restarting Tomcat, when I go to `https` + `://www.mydomain.com` the browser doesn't trust the cert, and it says

```
The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

What am I missing in my setup? Port 443 is enabled under firewall rules, and I have `Allow HTTPS traffic' checked. If I don't include this connector the URL can be accessed via HTTP.

Comment: Also, running `openssl s_client -connect localhost:443` says CONNECTED and I can see the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

in your google cloud plataform >> google compute engine, in properties of your VM, enable HTTPS in Session FIREWALL

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Tomcat version you are using some thing change, for example if you are using a version of Tomcat prior to Tomcat 7, you need to change "keystorePass" to "keypass". You are using both, I would try following the official documentation Tomcat [6.0](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) - [7.0](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) - [8.0](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html).

You can also check this [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34963308/how-to-install-ssl-on-gce-wordpress-apache) where you can find the steps to enable HTTPS protocol of your Apache service on Google Compute Engine.